# Glassfish log of uncaught exceptions

Tags: logging, glassfish

I have a fairly simple question:

Where do uncaught application errors are logged to in Glassfish 2.1?
In a webservice implementation an InvocationTargetException is raised and returned as a SoapFault. I would like to see the log of this Exception in order to trace its origin.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your domain folder is a logs folder. In there is the server.log. You should be able to find what you're looking for in there.

Comment: the server.log is there, but it does not contain anything related to the application error. Nothing seems to be appended since the server has started. It is a default installation.

Comment: Uncaught exceptions will get logged there. Are you catching it by chance?